# WPML in custom page templates

Tags: page-template, plugin-wpml

I have a Wordpress site translated from dansk to english using WPML. In it, I have a page which uses a custom page template to display the titles of all the posts. Sadly, it's displaying all posts twice: the original, and the translated.

This is the code I have:

```
<ul id="archive-list">
    <?php $args = array(
        'lang' => ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE,
        'numberposts' => '-1',
        'post_type' => 'post',
    );

    $myposts = get_posts($args);

    foreach($myposts as $post) : ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php   the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Does anyone have any idea what I need to do to get this page to display only the titles in the current language?

Answer (score 3):

For the language filter from WPML to take effect you have to allow filters in get_posts. Default this is off.

You can add `suppress_filters=0` to your get_posts args and it should work. See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Parameters

```
<ul id="archive-list">
    <?php $args = array( 'suppress_filters' => false, 'numberposts' => '-1', 'post_type' => 'post', );
    $myposts = get_posts($args);
    foreach($myposts as $post) : ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason that it is showing content in all languages, is because the language code arg should not be in the array.

I usually don't use surpress filters either.

If you have WPML properly set up, then you can go ahead and just use a custom query sth like:

```
<h2><?php _e('Archive','textdomain'); ?></h2>
   <ul id="archive-list">
      <?php $loop1 = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>
      <?php while ( $loop1->have_posts() ) : $loop1->the_post(); ?>
      <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Link to %s', 'textdomain' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
   </ul>
```